# Django REST - grab paramater value when part of the URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from location import views

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('city', views.CityViewSet, 'city')

app_name = 'location'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

when hitting the url `/api/location/city/25/` I get all the details for that object instance (with the id of 25) as expected.

**My question how do I grab the id number in my viewset?**

I know how to do it with just regular query parameters `/?id=25`, but can't seem to figure out how to do it when it's part of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL captures are available as the `kwargs` attribute (which is a `dict`) of the viewset instance. So from inside any viewset method, you can access them via `self.kwargs`.

In this case, as you're retrieving the instance (GET on detail), you can get the `pk` (primary key) via:

```
class CityViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Note that, I've assumed your **`lookup_url_kwarg`** is `pk` (the default); if you have something different you need to access by that key name as you can imagine.